# PRISMA: the command "db seed" is not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, prisma

I'm getting this error after running `npx prisma db seed`, I have followed the official documentation but I keep getting that error

```
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error could occur if the `ts-node` version is < 10.3.0. As a workaround, you can set the seed command in your `package.json` as

```
seed: tsc prisma/seed.ts && cat prisma/seed.js | node --input-type=\"commonjs\" && rm prisma/seed.js
```

This should fix the issue.